# How to do this symbol »

Tags: html, html-entities

How id this symbol done? » I have the right facing version of it. I can't do the left facing one. It's not the greater than or lesser than arrow keys on the board.

I also tried `&lsaquo;&lsaquo;`

[image]

»

Comment: Are you using UTF8? Simply copypaste it there.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to abuse a [quotation mark character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs) as an arrow. Don't do that.

Comment: Quick search for "Html Entities": http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/

Comment: Maybe you should use &laquo;&raquo ?

Comment: @Quentin: Why is it an abuse?

Comment: @biziclop — Because it is a quotation mark and not an arrow.

Comment: HTML entities? In 2012? Seriously, UTF8 is here for one reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« is a "left-pointing double angle quotation mark"

You should be able to represent it using:

```
&laquo;
```

Which makes the right-pointing version:

```
&raquo;
```

(Alternatively, you can just copy-and-paste in many places where its right be needed)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use &laquo; &raquo;?

Answer (score 2):

this is the `&raquo;` » html entity

Answer (score 1):

»

ITS HTML NAME IS `&raquo;`

ITS HTML NO. IS `&#187;`

ITS ASCII HEX CODE  : BB

ITS ASCII DEC VALUE:  187

And finally its description is

> right double angle quote

[**REFERENCE**](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)